Download video with image overlay using flutter_ffmpeg
In my app i have a one video playing on screen, and on top of video I have placed one image. I want to save this video together with overlay image. So how to download using flutter_ffmpeg with flutter code?
I have tried using flutter_ffmpeg but no idea how to video download with image overlay.
If anyone has ever try this issue before, request you to please help me.

"On top of video I have placed one image" How?? It's not clear what you've done exactly to play a video and then put a picture on top. (1) FFmpeg needs RGB pixels to make an output video frame (picture). Find a way to travel frame-by-frame in your playing video, where for each frame: you stop to grab an image of that video frame, add pixels of your image overlay on top, then send the edited pixels into FFmpeg for it to make an output video frame (in MP4 format).

If you don't know about working with pixels or any RGB then (2) Make sure a file of video and file of image exists at some URI location. Use FFmpeg to encode the two things overlaid (research the commands). As a first test: Can this example code work for you? I mean does it produce an output video file of your png image (change the mov into mp4 when testing it)?
